# Can we put 2 adverbs in a row?

Tags: grammar

Can we put two adverbs in a row without any "connecting" word in between?

Here's an example:

> I can stealthily physically harm this guy by using my telekinetic
>   power.

Is this grammatically correct? And if not why isn't it correct? And how can I fix the sentence?

Comment: Have you found examples of this sort of usage in published writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases yes, like this: **He spoke extremely intelligently**. Because intelligently is modifying spoke and extremely is modifying intelligently. In your case yes, because stealthily modifies physically(In a weird way.) and physically modifies harm.

Comment: I agree that *extremely* modifies *intelligently* in your example. But I would say that *physically harm* is a common enough expression that it acts as its own verb. *stealthily* modifies *physically harm* IMO.

Comment: I agree now that i look at it more.